# Is the Flajolet-Martin constant irrational? Is it transcendental?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Facebook has a [new tool](https://research.facebook.com/blog/three-and-a-half-degrees-of-separation/) to estimate the average path length between you and any other person on Facebook.  An interesting aspect of their method is the use of the [Flajolet-Martin algorithm](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlMa85.pdf).

In the Flajolet-Martin paper, they define a certain constant $\varphi = 2^{-1/2} e^\gamma \alpha^{-1}$, where $\alpha = \prod_{n \geq 1} ({{2n}\over{2n+1}})^{(-1)^{t(n)}}$ and $t(n)$ is the [ubiquitous Thue-Morse sequence](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/ubiq.ps), which counts the parity of number of $1$'s in the binary expansion of $n$.

Is $\alpha$ irrational?  Is it transcendental?  I offer $50 for a proof or disproof of either of these.

As an aside, I mention that the closely related infinite product $\prod_{n \geq 0} ({{2n+1}\over{2n+2}})^{(-1)^{t(n)}}$ is known to be equal to $2^{-1/2}$.  This was originally found by Woods and Robbins.

Comment: I didn' know that MO could be used to offer money. Strange, since you can offer up to 500 reputation points through a bounty.

Comment: Jeff is an old-fashioned guy. It also follows the tradition of Donald Knuth.

Comment: Jeffrey, could you please give a reference to Woods&Robbins result.

Comment: One can find the decimal digit expansion of this number here: https://oeis.org/A086744

Comment: D. R. Woods, Elementary problem proposal E 2692, Amer. Math. Monthly 85 (1978), 48.  Solution by Robbins.